# What is the right probability distribution for this ratio?

Tags: distributions, modeling

Suppose I have data that are generated like this:

1. An argument $i$ comes to $c_i \in \mathbb{N}_0$ conclusions, where $i \in N,|N|=n$.
2. A respondent assigns $f_{ij} \in \mathbb{N}_0$ fallacies to conclusion $j$ of argument $i$.
3. I divide the total number of fallacies by the number of conclusions to obtain an invalidity score $(\sum_j f_{ij})/c_i$.
4. Both $f_{ij}$ and $c_i$ are random variables.

What is a good probability distribution to describe this data model? Here are the ones I've considered:

1. A gamma distribution.
2. A continuous extension of the Poisson distribution (e.g. [see here](http://cmscience.blogspot.com/2008/04/mt-6-poisson-and-gamma-distribution.html)).
3. ?

Comment: what is the support of $f_i$?

Comment: You need to provide more information. Is the number of conclusions a random variable? If yes, what is its support?

Comment: Responded to your requests.

Comment: Surely $c_i$ and $f_{ij}$ are at the least non-negative *integers*.

Comment: Then $f_{ij}/c_i$ (and hence the sum in your question) is necessarily discrete, not continuous (though in some circumstances a continuous distribution may be a good approximation)

Comment: No, it is not necessarily discrete. For example, if there are 3 conclusions and a total of only 2 fallacies, the score is 2/3, which is not a natural number.

Comment: I'm afraid you're mistaken. "Discrete" is not the same thing as "takes integer values".

Comment: Ah, yes, right again!

Comment: Changed the title accordingly.

Comment: I think you have it now, but for later readers who may not be so quick to see it: a discrete distribution only takes countably many values. $f_{ij}/c_i$ only takes countably many values by the usual form of argument for the rationals. A similar argument can be applied to $\sum_j f_{ij}/c_i$; again, that only takes countably many values. It's thereby discrete. A continuous distribution, by contrast, takes uncountably many values, as does any mixture distribution with even the tiniest continuous component.

Comment: Hrm. This is (highly tangentially) related to the conclusion I am slowly arriving at that I can't just choose some pat standard distribution but may have to consider the ratio distribution (or its approximation). This would kind of suck, because I was hoping to just use a simple data generation model so I could just apply a standard Bayesian hierarchical regression model to examine the relationship between this ratio variable and other covariates.

Comment: In some situations, it may well be that the sum of such ratios can be fairly well approximated by something like a gamma, say, but it's likely to be a matter of trying it.